# How to download a pdf using fileSaver and Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf, filesaver.js

I stored some pdf file inside my angular 2 project. I want to download that file onclick of a button. Here is my html code-

```
<a class="btn-u btn-u-sm" (click)="SaveDemo()">Download <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right margin-left-5"></i></a>
```

And the component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RegistrationComponent } from '../registration/app.registration';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './app.pronto.html'
})
export class ProntoComponent {
   SaveDemo() {
      let file = new Blob(['../../../files/Skybase.pdf'], { type: 'application/pdf;charset=utf-8' });
      saveAs(file, 'Skybase.pdf')
   }
}
```

But a blank pdf is downloading. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If the file is on the same directory of the project

Why are you using so much coding for this , you can directly use `download` attribute of `a` tag

```
<a href="path_to_pdf" download>
```

> **NOTE :** If your path is correct , you file will be downloaded otherwise it
>   will be blank , same issue is in your code. Check your file path and make sure its correct.

---

> `<a href="path_to_pdf" download="new_filename">`
>
> Specifies the new filename for the downloaded file

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download="w3logo">W3 Logo</a>
```

Comment: i tried that too but its not happening instead its go to my home page. i have used routing and add <base href="/"> in my html page. i think thats why href="" is not working

Comment: will you please share the path where you have stored the pdf file ?

Comment: I have 2 directories app and files in same level. html is locating app>solutions>pronto>pronto.html and files>Skybase.pdf

Comment: try to use this path ../files/Skybase.pdf

Comment: i tried this href="../files/Skybase.pdf" download="downloaded_Skybase.pdf" but it saysFailed-no file

Comment: issue is with only file location nothing else , so you have to find out the correct path now try with only "files/Skybase.pdf"